# Edit JavaScript variables externally

Tags: php, javascript, edit

I have created a JS script which has more optional settings.

So, somewhere near the beginning of the file I have something like this:

```
var doThat = true;
var playThat = false;
...
```

This script will be used by users and not by developers so they may not know how to edit a JavaScript file. How can I create a kind of admin-panel which would allow to change some variables in a JavaScript file.

I was thinking about creating an interface which will contain radio buttons to choose those values, now the problem is: how do I actually save those changes in the `.js` file? Should I use PHP to edit the js file directly or is there some better way?

Comment: I would go with the PHP approach: Receive and check the values, udate the the JavaScript file and serve the latest version.

Comment: it would be easy to store your custom variables in database with PHP, and pass that variables value to your JS file.

Comment: If I save to database than each user will have to query the database just two get two boolean values... And all that on each and every page the script is requested.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on who needs to have access to those variables.

1. If these variables are shared between all your visitors you should definitly save them on the server.
2. If you need them only per user and per session, save them via PHP in a session or with cookies at the user. Cookies can be created with JS aswell
3. If you need them only per user but persitant you can use the localStorage-Object. Nearly all modern browsers support this.
4. If you have a login-script and you need the variables persistent and per user you should use php, since this is the most reliable way to identify a user over time.

Comment: The variables need to be changed permanently in the JavaScript file as the file will be served to many other visitors. I need to save them on the server, but I would like to know what the best approach would be.

Comment: But any user can make changes? If yes, save it via php directly in the JS file. Perhapes create an own JS file that only has those variables.

Comment: Only the administrator can change the file. But I said that the administrator is not a "developer" so he needs a user-interface to change the file.

Comment: Ok, so there is only one user who needs to change the JS file. Well I would make a seperate JS file for those JS variables that the admin can change. This JS file is created with a PHP script that also handles the user-interface. So when the admin-user sends the new variables eg via POST, you create/overwrite this variables.js with the new values. This will speed up the server a bit

Answer (score 0):

for this make an interface with radio button. then make all changes and save it to database.The saved result's corresponding work will be performed.

Comment: If I save to database than each user will have to query the database just two get two boolean values...

Comment: user will not query the database. It will be performed by your programming. User only get previledge. giving you an example:- suppose user named "ripa" will only get priviledge for view users. this codition is set by admin.when user "ripa" logged into the system then she only can see the users.This part is automatically done by programming."ripa" user not doing any code.

Comment: I know... I just said that the DB will be queried for each file request. That's very inefficient and could be avoided.

Comment: ok I understand.If you find any better solution then please post it here.I also want to know that.please post.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have a PHP file that writes these JavaScript variables, in the following way:

```
$doThatVariable = true; // This variable could be retrieved from a database
$playThatVariable = false; // This variable could be retrieved from a database

// This code could be ran on relevant pages to correctly set up the JavaScript variables
print("<script type=\"text/javascript\">
     var doThat = " . $doThatVariable . ";
     var playThat = " . $playThatVariable . ";
     </script>\n");
```

You would then be able to use the `doThat` and `playThat` variables in your JavaScript.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is that I simply provide the `.js` file as a script to be included on pages, adding any additional includes will just make my script be harder to use (having more files to include).

Comment: @Cristy This is the only extra thing you'd need to include on the page, so it sets up the JavaScript variables correctly.